# bluemix runtime: auto vertical scalability?

Tags: node.js, scalability, ibm-cloud

It is clear that the auto-scale service allows to automatically scale-in and scale-out an application horizontally. And that I can manually scale vertically my application too by MANUALLY increasing/decreasing the memory.

Is there a way to AUTOMATICALLY increase and decrease the memory associated to the node.js instances based on some rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note Bluemix charges the application based on GB * Hour. So by large you will be charged similarly among vertical scaling and horizontal scaling. However, vertical scaling does improves memory usage efficiency because there is less memory overhead (e.g., you load the node.js runtime only once rather than twice ore more). But horizontal scaling also has its merits:

- Better availability due to increased app instances;
- Better concurrency due to distributed processes;
- Potential better exploration of CPU resource (because of the way CGroup works for CPU allocation).

So if your application is memory-hungry, allocating large memory for each instance would make sense. Otherwise if the app is CPU hungry, then horizontal scaling may work better. You can do some benchmark to evaluate the response time and throughput impact of both options.

Answer (score 1):

The Auto-Scaling add-on in Bluemix monitors the chosen resources against their policies and increases or decreases the number of instances, not vertical scaling (memory).

Why does your node app's memory requirements grow? Can you offload some of it by using a database or cashing service? Relying on increasing memory when needed is currently a bad practice because it will require a small downtime as your application restarts.

Comment: Yes, I will use data cache, that's a great suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Ram mentioned. The Auto-Scaling service doesn't currently support vertical scaling.

You can scale horizontally by discrete numbers of instances or by a % of the total number of instances.

See the [docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/Auto-Scaling/index.html#autoscaling) for which metrics are supported by each application type

edit: typo!